# Does this mechanism use the Buffer or the Cache?

Tags: python, buffer

As far as I know, a buffer is something that has yet to be "written" to disk, while a cache is something that has been "read" from the disk and stored for later use.

But for this mechanism: In python, when a memory is not being used, there exists such an area which will be kept by the system for the next usage instead of just releasing immediately.

I am wondering does this area belong to the Buffer or the Cache?

Thanks.

Comment: A cache is something that stores data for repeated use. A buffer is something that smoothes dataflow mainly by storing data in advance to compensate dataflow rates lower than required by the sink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the mechanism you mentioned is related to Python's memory management and garbage collection.
This isn't related to buffering or caching data. Cache and Buffer are different things, which used to reduce disk-related operations (reading or writing data to disk).

Python's memory mechanism talks about allocating memory from the operating system.

Yoy can read more about Python's Garbage Collector [here](https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/) and the difference between cache and buffer [here](https://superuser.com/a/433951).